# Show that a function is a probability generating function

Tags: probability, generating-functions

I'm doing past papers in order to revise for  exams in June and my university irritatingly doesn't provide any mark schemes and I'm very stuck on a question.

The question says:

Let $g(z)=\frac{2}{3}+(14-5z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Show that exists a nonnegative integer-valued random variable whose probability generating function is $g$.

Attempt:

So, I thought I wanted to show that there exists $X$ such that $g(z)=\mathbb{E}(z^{X})=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p_{X}(k)z^{k}$. 
So, first I checked that $g(1)=1$ which it does.

Then I just differentiated $g$ to find a general formula for the pmf of $X$. So, I got

$g(0)=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}} \Rightarrow p_{X}(0)=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}$

Then $g'(z)=\frac{5/2}{(14-5z)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \Rightarrow g''(z)=\frac{75/4}{(14-5z)^{\frac{5}{2}}} \Rightarrow ... \Rightarrow g^{(k)}(z)=\frac{5^{k}(2k)!}{2^{2k}k!(14-5z)^{\frac{2k+1}{2}}}$

Therefore $p_{X}(k)=\frac{5^{k}(2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^{2}(14-5z)^{\frac{2k+1}{2}}}$ for $k=1,2,...$

This just seemed too messy, so I thought my method must be incorrect?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is fairly easy to see, by looking at the power series expansion of our function, that the coefficients are non-negative. So now the only issue is whether the coefficients have sum $1$. To verify this, put $z=1$.

Comment: So, the criteria for being a valid pgf for some random variable is that the power expansion has nonnegative coefficients that sum to one?

Comment: For a random variable that takes on values in integers $\ge 0$, yes.

Comment: And, by definition of a pgf, if a random variable has one then it must take values in the nonnegative integers, right?

Comment: Yes. The problem was easier than you thought it to be.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks very much!

Comment: You are welcome.