# General conditions for a function to a probability generating function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

To ensure that $g(z)=2/3 + (14-5x)^{-1/2}$ is a [probability generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function), we [check that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/746885/240768) the coefficients of the power series meet the probability axioms:

- non negativity of coefficients
- sum of coefficients =  1

For $G(s)=1-\alpha(1-s)^{\beta}$, on the other hand, we [check that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2561719/240768)

- the function lies between 0 and 1 for the variable between 0 and 1.
- infinite differentiability
- left hand limit of the function at 1 is 1.

**Question 1:** Are the two methods equivalent? Can someone explain why each of the checks in the second method is required, and what it checks for?

**Question 2:** What are the general conditions for a function to be a PGF?

Comment: $1-(1-x)^{2}$ satisfies the second set of conditions but it is not a generating function.

Comment: So then the second set of conditions is not correct?